# how to add html control "anchor tag" dynamically in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview, anchor

I have added ASP button to the GridView using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DynamicTemplate
/// </summary>
public class DynamicTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
```

{

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType templateType;
System.Collections.Hashtable htControls = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
System.Collections.Hashtable htBindPropertiesNames = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
System.Collections.Hashtable htBindExpression = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

public DynamicTemplate(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType type)
{
    templateType = type;
}

public void AddControl(WebControl wbControl, String BindPropertyName, String BindExpression)
{
    htControls.Add(htControls.Count, wbControl);
    htBindPropertiesNames.Add(htBindPropertiesNames.Count, BindPropertyName);
    htBindExpression.Add(htBindExpression.Count, BindExpression);

}

public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();

    for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
    {

        //clone control 
        Control cntrl = CloneControl((Control)htControls[i]);

        switch (templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:
                break;
            case ListItemType.Item:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                break;
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:
                break;
        }
    }
    ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);

    container.Controls.Add(ph);

}
public void Item_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)sender;
    GridViewRow ri = (GridViewRow)ph.NamingContainer;
    for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Control tmpCtrl = (Control)htControls[i];
            String item1Value = ""; //(String)DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString());
            if (tmpCtrl.ID == "btnEdit")
            {
                item1Value = "Edit"; //(String)DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString());
            }
            else if (tmpCtrl.ID == "btnDelete")
            {
                item1Value = "Delete"; //(String)DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString());


            }
            else
            {
                Guid value = new Guid(DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString()).ToString());
                String valueString = value.ToString();
                item1Value = valueString;
            }
            Control ctrl = ph.FindControl(tmpCtrl.ID);
            Type t = ctrl.GetType();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString());

            pi.SetValue(ctrl, item1Value.ToString(), null);
        }

    }



}

private Control CloneControl(System.Web.UI.Control src_ctl)
{
    Type t = src_ctl.GetType();
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    Control dst_ctl = (Control)obj;
    PropertyDescriptorCollection src_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src_ctl);
    PropertyDescriptorCollection dst_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dst_ctl);

    for (int i = 0; i < src_pdc.Count; i++)
    {

        if (src_pdc[i].Attributes.Contains(DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.Content))
        {

            object collection_val = src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl);
            if ((collection_val is IList) == true)
            {
                foreach (object child in (IList)collection_val)
                {
                    Control new_child = CloneControl(child as Control);
                    object dst_collection_val = dst_pdc[i].GetValue(dst_ctl);
                    ((IList)dst_collection_val).Add(new_child);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dst_pdc[src_pdc[i].Name].SetValue(dst_ctl, src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl));
        }
    }

    return dst_ctl;

}
```

}

Code file is ::

Bind Method for gridview:

```
        TemplateField t = new TemplateField();
        DynamicTemplate mt = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.Item);

        Button btnEdit = new Button();
        btnEdit.ID = "btnEdit";
        btnEdit.Visible = true;
        btnEdit.CommandArgument = PrimaryKey;
        btnEdit.OnClientClick = "return confirm_Edit();";
        btnEdit.Text = " Submit";
        btnEdit.CssClass = "EditButton";
        btnEdit.Style.Add("margin-right", "5px");
        mt.AddControl(btnEdit, "Text", "Edit");



        Button btnDelete = new Button();
        btnDelete.ID = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm_delete();";
        btnDelete.Visible = true;
        btnDelete.Text = " Submit";
        btnDelete.CssClass = "DeleteButton";
        mt.AddControl(btnDelete, "Text", "Delete");

        t.ItemTemplate = mt;
        t.HeaderText = "Activity";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(t);
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now i am facing the below problem: 
how can i add HTML anchor tag on the place of ASP Button to grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added it like below :

```
  TemplateField t = new TemplateField();
        DynamicTemplate mt = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.Item);

        HtmlImage img = new HtmlImage();
        img.ID = "btnEdit";
        img.Src = "~/images/image.gif";
        img.Alt = "An image";
        img.Attributes.Add("class", "cssimage");
        mt.AddControl(img, "Text", "Edit");
        t.ItemTemplate = mt;
        t.HeaderText = "Activity";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(t);
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
HyperLink lnkDelete = new HyperLink();
lnkDelete.Text = "Link text";
lnkDelete.NavigateUrl = "deletepage.aspx";
```

Have you tried something like this?